# mocha+chai+jsdom-Can't load custom modules Directories

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mocha.js, chai

I'm working with a multi entry point app, It heavily using common components and I loaded it from resolve section in webpack (see webpack file)

webpack file

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.css', '.scss', '.jsx', '.json'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'common']
}
```

But issue is when I'm going to test that component it can't load directories from common folder, because I didn't defined it as module directory, So Is there a way to load custom modules Directories in test environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, we can define custom module path with using `app-module-path` package

install

```
npm install app-module-path --save
```

require in your file, before any require() calls:

```
require('app-module-path').addPath(process.env.PWD + '/common');
```

then you can import your component from `/common/util/Base`

```
import Base from 'util/Base';
```